# Python doesn't run immediately after called by php

Tags: php, python, multithreading

I use php to invoke Python program,

```
exec("/usr/bin/python /path/to/my.py >/dev/null &")
```

Sometimes it works fine,but sometimes  it just doesn't work,there's no Python thread running.

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

Nothing.it looks like my code runs randomly.anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong type,it's /usr/bin/python

Comment: I would assume that your python just ends earlier than you'd expect in some cases?

Comment: I have changed the .py file to the simplest code,just let it be like below,and it worked fine when I run it on shell:
but still when I invoke it from php,it didn`t print any strings into out.txt .all  files are in mode 777.

#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import os


def main():
        with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/out.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write("hello world out.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

Comment: I made a mistake,the script path was wrong.